# Cycles Render Floor Rendering Black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

So I am creating this field scene in Blender. Everything was going well and it looked great in the viewport render but in the final render, the ground is rendering black. I don't know what could be causing this. I went through the forums but couldn't find anything to help. I can answer any questions and I wish I could upload the file but it's over 30MB.

Thank you for any help!

ViewPort Render

[image: viewport render]

Final Render

[image: FinalRender]

Node Stack for Ground

[image: NodeStack]

Render Settings

[image: Render Settings]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Have you checked if there are no overlapping faces (Z-Fighting)?

Comment: @moonboots there was a duplicate of the grid i used causing that issue! After deleting it everything was fine